# What are the advantages of keeping the secondary IPv4 address with the same subnet mask as the primary IPv4 address?

Tags: networking, routing

Let's say, that I have a server with an `eth0` interface with IPv4 address `192.168.0.1/24`. I have an application running in this server which has to bind to another IPv4 address in the `192.168.0.0/24` network, but rest of the applications running in the server need to keep using `192.168.0.1` as a source address for egress connections. Let's say, that this another address has to be `192.168.0.2`. I could add `192.168.0.2/24` to `eth0` and ensure with the `ip route change default via 192.168.0.254 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.1` that by default the outgoing connections use `192.168.0.1` as a source address. Alternatively, I could add `192.168.0.2/32` instead of `192.168.0.2/24` to `eth0` and then I don't need to touch the routing table.

Are there any advantages of keeping the secondary address with the same subnet mask as the primary address? Or more specifically based on my example, what would be the difference between configuring `192.168.0.2/32` on network interface instead of `192.168.0.2/24`?

Comment: serverfault.com maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but specifying a mask of `/32` might imply a point-to-point link, which might disable the use of ARP for it. That could cause some unexpected behavior. You *could* work around it with further settings (possibly at both ends of the connection that uses the 192.168.0.2 address).

But that becomes just the kind of overly clever hack that will cause your phone to blow up on your vacation with messages from your co-workers: "*I swapped a broken NIC, this service broke, and I cannot even figure out how it used to work before, help!!!*"

Or it might be yourself after a year or so, returning to this system and wondering: "*I remember I did something very clever here, but what were all the parts of it?*"

The routing table should be one of the first things that gets looked at when troubleshooting a system that has more than one IP address, so a customized default route there could be easily discovered by a competent troubleshooter.
"*Hmm... the default route has an extra attribute that specifies the source address... that means there must be more than one possible source address configured for that network segment!*"

That would hopefully lead the person in question to run `ip address show` (since the old `ifconfig` will not show extra addresses added to interfaces with `ip address add`... ask me how I know) and discover the second address, which would then be otherwise completely normal, with no risk of "point-to-point" special cases.

So, in short, I would argue that the use of `/24` and routing table customization will make the configuration more explicit, and easier to figure out if/**when** needed.

But I admit, this is almost completely opinion-based.